# What's an alternative to getChildFragmentManager() in API 28?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I got trouble with reloading fragments in a viewpager. 
Due to searches I must use getChildFragmentManager() in case of nested fragments, but as I can see per documentation the method and the android.app.fragment itself are deprecated in API level 28. So are there any alternatives to solve this issue?

Comment: You should be using Support Library fragments.

Comment: Yup, i'm using androidx.fragment.app.Fragment

Answer (score 3):

Only `android.app.Fragment` and the related classes are deprecated. You can continue to use `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment` and its `getChildFragmentManager()` on all API 14+ devices.

Comment: I am using androidx.fragment.app.Fragment but i am unable to get a reference to getChildFragmentManager(), the tool says the method can't be resolved, cleaning and rebuilding do not work either

Comment: Please include your code on where you're calling `getChildFragmentManager()`. That method certainly exists on the `Fragment` class.

Answer (score 1):

When calling `getChildFragmentManager()`, you might also be calling `FRAGMENT_DIALOG`, therefore you need to also replace `android.app.DialogFragment` with `androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment`.